# How to set SpecificVersion metadata for Visual Studio 2008 AssemblyFolders

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I've added a registry key like `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\AssemblyFolders\MyFolder` with a folder that has my assemblies in it, and I can see those assemblies from Visual Studio when viewing the "Add Reference" dialog.

My question is how can I tell Visual Studio that it should add a vague reference instead of a very specific one?

For example, in my .csproj file, I see `<Reference Include="System.Xml" />` without a version, culture or public key token.  But when I add my own reference, it specifies all of those things, meaning my build will break if I upgrade an assembly.

Alternatively, is there a way to make Visual Studio set the `SpecificVersion` metadata to `False`?  This would accomplish the same goal.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is by design. The IDE does not allow for your assemblies to be added without a version number. This makes sense in the case that you might be developing against a particular version of components.

If your code checks the version number, you must explicitly choose the new version as the author of a client assembly. Otherwise you could be surprised by breaking changes introduced in the referenced assembly.

**Edit**
This article on Partial Assembly References at MSDN [link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0a7zy9z5%28VS.71%29.aspx) is probably the way you want to get around this problem. I found this in another SO post [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861010/is-it-possible-to-have-version-independent-dll-references-in-a-class). Note: In this case, you will use Assembly.Load, which will look in the application's directory.

Comment: Partial references in the csproj file are resolved at build time, so whether I specify version, culture, etc, or not, my assembly will have a reference that includes all of those things as long as the build finds a matching assembly.