# ADO.NET Provider for SAP HANA - Version mismatch issue

Tags: ado.net, hana

I have a WPF application which is using ADO.NET client for SAP HANA ( Version 1.0.9.0) in my local development environment and i have added the same reference of SAP.DATA.HANA.v4.5.dll in my code. The connection works fine.

When i try to run the same application on a server which is having a different version of ADO.NET client , it throws error. 
It should refer to the client from the location(C:\Program Files\sap\hdbclient\ado.net\v4.5) instead of version number ?

Can someone please explain if i am doing something wrong.

Comment: I am having the same issue last application crashed where I have used so I have to create new application and getting this problem mismatch version of sap.data.hana

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything wrong. But I think you're missing a key piece of knowledge about assembly references. And there are ways to deal with it, both for you and SAP.

When .NET references an assembly, it does so against the exact version used at compile time. Which means if at runtime the version number is different, it fails by default. Differences in the signing key used for strong-named assemblies or cultures can also cause the assembly loading to fail. This [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277817/compile-a-version-agnostic-dll-in-net/284462#284462) discusses that and suggests an approach to dealing with it using the `AssemblyResolve` event. You might have a lot more to do if your application has a complex plugin loading mechanism, but if it's really simple, you can get it updated with minimal effort. Of course, you'll still have issues if the client DB makes a breaking change, but they'll be different issues.

Another approach is to edit your application's [configuration file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/index) to [redirect assembly versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions) yourself. Sometimes Nuget packages are even set up to automatically insert these redirects into the application configuration file. Unfortunately this isn't an easy strategy with HANA given how frequently the versions change. And you need to know the exact version that's present to do this. So if you're deploying your application to multiple clients with different HANA versions, it could be a bit of a nightmare.

The sad thing is that there's already an existing mechanism in place for dealing with this sort of thing by the vendor who publishes the library. It's called a [publisher policy assembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/how-to-create-a-publisher-policy), but SAP botched its delivery of the policy assembly by including (and embedding) the most useless binding redirect ever conceived.

Normally, with a binding redirect, the purpose is to allow for seamless upgrading of an assembly to a newer version as long as your types haven't changed their public interfaces significantly. All you do is specify the range of versions that can be handled by this version in the XML.

SAP, however has this as their binding redirect element:

```
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.120.0-1.0.120.0" newVersion="1.0.120.0" />
```

Which does you the wonderful favor of allowing **only** the currently installed version of their DB client (in this case, `1.0.120.0`). And no, that DLL doesn't change its ADO.NET classes enough for this sort of strict versioning. In my case, everything about the different assembly versions was exactly the same.

Had I the ability to get in touch with someone sane on the HANA team with enough clout to fix this, I'd suggest they set the `oldVersion` attribute properly to the oldest upgradable version and upgrade every subsequent driver package. So if you've installed `1.0.120.0`, it'd look something more like this with the :

```
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.9.0-1.0.120.0" newVersion="1.0.120.0" />
```

And then it could be used by any software on the machine without extra effort. I mean, it's in the GAC. It wouldn't be that much effort for them to make this significantly easier. Although they'd need to patch all versions of the HANA client, as many applications (even those shipped by SAP) are tied to specific HANA versions. If they only fixed it in the latest version, we wouldn't see the benefits for several years.