# Connection error when trying to create entity model from SAP HANA DB

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net, hana, sapb1

I am trying to build a ADO.NET entity model from a SAP HANA database. This is for SAP B1. This process is pretty straight forward using MS Server/MySql etc.

However, when I follow the steps of creating this HANA model, I get the following error below on clicking "Test Connection":

> general error: database 'EOH_CCL_TEST' does not exist
>
> [image]

I have added a reference for `Sap.Data.Hana.v4.5.dll`.

Version is 1.0.120.0.

The database exists and I am able to perform queries on it as can be seen below.

Note: I am using the same credentials as I used to log into SAP HANA Studio.

What am I missing here?

There is a previous post: [ADO.NET Provider for SAP HANA - Version mismatch issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45233832/ado-net-provider-for-sap-hana-version-mismatch-issue)

But in that issue, the user was able to make the connection.

[image]

Comment: Going from the screenshot you are not using a HANA system with multiple database containers. In this “classic” setup there is no separate admin object “database” and connections don’t take a database name. Just put in hostname and port and leave the database name empty. The `EOH_CCL_TEST` is indeed just the schema name. Beyond that, it’s really not a good idea to use `SYSTEM` user for working with data or really anything beyond bootstrapping the system.

Comment: This worked. You should put this as answer.

Comment: Just added as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going from the screenshot you are not using a HANA system with multiple database containers. In this “classic” setup there is no separate admin object “database” and connections don’t take a database name.

Just put in hostname and port and leave the database name empty. The `EOH_CCL_TEST` is indeed just the schema name.

Beyond that, it’s really not a good idea to use SYSTEM user for working with data or really anything beyond bootstrapping the system.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the schema name EOH_CCL_TEST as database name. The database name is different to the schema name. Did you logon to the SYSTEMDB database or to a tenant database in HANA Studio? Using the used DB name should solve the issue for you. PS: I also do not think that you need to add a port in the hostname property field.

Comment: I logged into the SYSTEM database. I will try removing the port and see where it goes.

Comment: Removing the port does not solve the issue. I get the error "Connect failed (no reachable host left)".

Comment: And you did set SYSTEM as the database name instead of the schema name?

Comment: I am not following you. I did not set SYSTEM as the DB name. EOH_CCL_TEST is the database name. I thought SYSTEM was the equivalent to "sa" when it comes to Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: No EOH_CCL_TEST is not the database name, but the schema name.

Comment: I have now set SYSTEM as DB name and EOH_CCL_TEST as schema name. In the above image, what does one supply as User ID and Password?

Comment: A user existing in the chosen database.

Comment: Unfortunately I get: "general error: database 'SYSTEM' does not exist"

Comment: In case you did not create a tenant db with that name, no such db will exist. The name for the system db is SYSTEMDB (if you are looking for that)?